# Moving a sprite via a gyroscope

Tags: java, android, sprite, gyroscope

So i have 2 questions
first i am curious if its possible to move a sprite via a gyroscope

second if so, do i need to specify the movement of the sprite's X & Y or will that be automatic
and/or do i get the gyro's X & Y movement or is that automatic
#beginner

```
package com.thejames.thesphere;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ImageView thesphere;
private SensorManager sensorManager;
private Sensor gyroscopeSensor;
private SensorEventListener gyroscopeEventListener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    sensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    gyroscopeSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE);

    gyroscopeEventListener = new SensorEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent sensorEvent) {
            if (sensorEvent.values(2) > 0.5f) {
                //Sphere+Movement
            } else if (sensorEvent.values(2) < -0.5f) {
                //Sphere-Movement
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

        }
    };

    thesphere = findViewById(R.id.thesphere);
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    sensorManager.registerListener(gyroscopeEventListener, gyroscopeSensor, sensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);
}
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    sensorManager.unregisterListener(gyroscopeEventListener);
}
```

}